# CSS grid - Line-based placement

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have been playing with css grid for week now and I am trying make a similar layout as the [Line-based placement](https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/yNmyoM) by Rachel Andrew.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="box a">Heading</h1>
  <div class="box b">Image</div>
  <p class="box c">Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
    }

    .box {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 150%;
    }

    .a {
        grid-column: 1 / 3;
        grid-row: 1;
    }
    .b {
        grid-column: 3 ;
        grid-row: 1 / 3;
    }
    .c {
        grid-column: span 2 ;
        grid-row: 2 ;
    }
```

The layout changes completely when I replace the div tags with h1 and p.

[Expected layout with div tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg38e.png)

But when I use h1 and p tags it actually looks like this

[Actual layout with h1 and p tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axkDq.png)

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: It would be better if you post your `html` & `css`

Comment: You can see the code on Rachel Andrew's example I posted. The only thing I change is the div tags to h1 and p, which messes up the layout.

Comment: still, you should be posting your code in the question *itself* for clarity purposes, external links can go 404 in the future..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reseting the margin of the h1 and p elements did the trick.